# requireJS this context change within the callback

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs, this

I've the following code:

```
require([templateName], function(template, view){
    console.log(this); // outputs Window object
    this.renderTemplate(template, {
        articles: this.collection.toJSON() // rises error
    });
});
```

now to make this work I need to change 'this' context as it is outside of it. How to achieve it?

/// EDIT - full code

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore', 'article/collections/Articles', 'generic-view-decorator','error-handler-decorator'],
function($, Backbone, _, ArticlesCollection,  GenericViewDecorator, ErrorHelperDecorator) {
    var ArticleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(config) {
            this.initializeCollection(ArticlesCollection, this.buildResourceUrl({
                domain : 'oskszu.vgnett.no',
                path : 'vgnett-dt/'+config.config.section + '/json',
                query : [{
                    key : 'limit',
                    val : config.config.limit
                }]
            }));
            this.initializeErrorCapturing(this.collection);
        },
        render: function() {
            if(!this.collection.length) {
                this.trigger('error-600');
            } else {
                var templateName = 'text!widgets/widgets/article/templates/article.tpl';
                require([templateName]).call(this, function(template){
                    console.log(this);
                    /*this.renderTemplate(template, {
                        articles: this.collection.toJSON()
                    });*/
                }, this);
            }
        }
    });

    _.extend(ArticleView.prototype, GenericViewDecorator);
    _.extend(ArticleView.prototype, ErrorHelperDecorator);

    return ArticleView;
}
);
```

Comment: I dont understand, what do you want "this" to be? require is used to separate code and handle dependencies and set scopes so "this" in a require/define statement shoudn't be anything else i think.

Comment: It defineatly will - than 'this' will be equal to 'Window' object - and It shouldn't be. I want to pass 'this' context from the outside of the require() function.

Comment: Why are you using require.js in combination with a function bound to the Window object (this.renderTemplate)? Isn't the renderTemplate function supposed to be a property in an object you require with require.js?

Comment: 'this' in this situation is backbone's view - but it doesn't matter. I want to pass 'any' external 'this' within the require method.

Comment: I've attached the whole file... to shows the context.

Comment: have you try: var self = this; then later self.yourFunction instead of this.yourFunction ?

Comment: no... this is a workaround in my opinion.

Comment: use `apply` on `renderTemplate`: 

`this.renderTemplate(template, {
        articles: this.collection.toJSON()
    }).apply(this);`

Comment: it has to be one level up - but yea... what's what I've ment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it in the following way (for the future generations ;) ):

```
        render: function() {
            if(!this.collection.length) {
                this.trigger('error-600');
            } else {
                var templateName = 'text!widgets/widgets/article/templates/article.tpl';
                require([templateName], (function(template){
                    console.log(this);
                    /*this.renderTemplate(template, {
                        articles: this.collection.toJSON()
                    });*/
                }).call(this));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand how that will work. Won't Function.call() call the function immediately? Maybe you meant to use Function.bind()?